# Returning NULL with return type declarations

Tags: php, php-7, type-hinting, php-7.1

I was refactoring a codebase for use with PHP7, particularly implementing scalar type hints and return type hints, when I encountered an problem.

I have a class with some properties, one of which an id. This id is not mandatory (you can construct an object without setting the id). When creating a new object of this class you don't set the id, and it gets an id as soon as it is inserted into the db (by a separate mapper class).

This mapper class needs to check if the object already exists in the db, and it does this by checking if the id is set:

```
if(empty($exampleObject->getId())) {
    // Insert object
} else {
    // Update object
}
```

I was applying return type hints to every function in my codebase, and the problem is that the function `getId()` can't return *NULL* if I enforce an *int* return type. It TypeErrors, even without having strict typing enabled:

> **Fatal error**:  Uncaught TypeError: Return value of ExampleClass::getId() must be of the type integer, null returned

I considered not setting a return type hint for this getter, but I then realised the problem is probably not the return type hinting, but the fact that I'm using mixed return types. I remember reading somewhere that using mixed return types is a bad thing, but I'm not sure how to tackle this without using mixed return types. I could:

- Throw an exception in the getter, and design the check in the mapper class so that it catches that exception.
- Catch the TypeError exception, and use that to indicate the id is not set.
- Make the id property public, so I can call *isset* directly on that.
- Add a different method `hasId() return isset($this->id)`

Frankly, don't really like any of these solutions, and I was wondering if there's a better option. What's the best practise for cases like this?

Also, shouldn't I only get a TypeError if I have strict typing enabled? I thought PHP7 defaulted to "weak type hints".

Comment: try `int?` as return-type

Comment: @tkausl Is that implemented? I didn't know about this feature (it's not in the PHP documentation), but I found [this RFC](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/nullable_types) (nullable types). Is this what you're referring to? If so, this is a draft targeting PHP 7.1.

Comment: Oh.. I was sure i've seen this somewhere but wasn't sure where, sorry.

Comment: @tkausl, it's C# syntaxis!

Comment: re: only getting `TypeError`s in strict typing mode, that's not quite how it works. PHP will try to coerce between types by default, but where this isn't possible it will throw a `TypeError`, at least for user functions written in PHP. Built-in/extension functions, however, don't throw `TypeError` unless in strict mode.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

PHP 7.1 added [nullable types](http://wiki.php.net/rfc/nullable_types), where you put a question mark before the type name to mark the return type as accepting both that type and null:

```
public function getId(): ?int {
    /* … */
}
```

If you're still on PHP 7.0, I suggest omitting the type declaration and using a docblock.

Comment: Thanks. So that means there's nothing wrong per se with returning *NULL*?

Comment: Yeah, though there's some arguments for avoiding `null`, but they're not universally applicable.

Comment: beside the point, but just thought i'd point out that PSR2 specifies open bracket for class & methods be on new line ;)

Comment: @wired00 I'm a contrarian :p

Comment: @Compizfox Still you have to set starting value to null by property declaration otherwise it does not work. Sounds like a joke when I have a default null value by injection too and explicitly set the property to null when the parameter is not given.

Answer (score 0):

Using `null` means using object-oriented approaches because value types cannot be null. So it might be useful to use class wrapper around integer type. For example, [SplInt](http://php.net/manual/ru/class.splint.php) from SPL types.